# Using ContextCompat.getColor in fragment Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, colors

I have a check box in fragment and trying to set text color on it using ContextCompat.getColor

the code

```
optionCb.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,android.R.color.white));
```

It shows error

```
required : Context 
Found : fragmentactivity
```

Even used

```
optionCb.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity.applicationContext,android.R.color.white));
```

Still shows error

What should be the context object here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

was able to solve by using requireActivity()

```
optionCb.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), android.R.color.black));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ContextCompat.getColor()` accepts two arguments -- the first of which is a non-null `Context` object.

If you're writing code in Kotlin, Android Studio is likely complaining about the `Context` object you're passing to `getColor()` being nullable. The `context` and `activity` parameters available to `Fragment`s are nullable in Android.

As others have already mentioned, you can use the `requireContext()` function. However, while this will satisfy Android Studio, it should be used with caution since it will throw an `IllegalStateException` if the Fragment's `context` is null (the context of a Fragment is not always available).

My recommendation would be to set the text color in your xml layout file if at all possible. If you have to do it programmatically, the safest way is to handle the null case:

```kotlin
    context
        ?.let { ContextCompat.getColor(it, android.R.color.white) }
        ?.also { optionsCb.setTextColor(it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `requiredActivity` or `requiredContext` instead of `activity`

Answer (score 0):

```
optionCb.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),android.R.color.white));
```